# What happened to code highlighting?

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

It seems that code highlighting has been disabled for some time on this site (at least on my side?). I'm not sure, but I think that there was once the possibility to have such a feature, but either my memories are flawed, or the fact that StackOverflow went on to use highlight.js instead of Google Highlight is the reason. It seems however that there was a possibility to do so in the past, as [there was a question about improving the code highlighting functionality](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386/syntax-highlighting-for-quantum-programming-languages).

It seems that creating code with

````
```python
````

or with

````
```lang-python
````

yields the same result, that is no syntax highlighting.

Is there a procedure to do, either on the user side or on the developers', to get back this functionality?

Comment: I'm not aware of any change on our side. Some network-wide change having occurred is possible of course, but are we sure this was ever actually a thing on this site? It's not clear from the linked question whether that was ever actually implemented

Comment: @glS As I said, I'm not sure this was ever a feature on this site! There was [a proposal](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/133/10454) to add code highlighting to this site, to which people seemed to respond positively. Thus, if this was never implemented, should I change my question to know whether it is possible to get such a feature? But that would be a duplicate of the aforementioned question, so what should I do?

Comment: don't worry it's fine like this, I'll ask about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to eventually update this. Anyway, I asked, it was not implemented; it is now. It is to be activated on a tag-per-tag basis, so let us know (via flag or meta post) of any tag that need to be associated with any language.